# How to use grid layout in a card game

Tags: android

I'm developing the memory card game that has twelve cards, three rows made up of four cards.
To do this, the layout consists of three linear layouts that contain four textview each.

How can I do in another way using a grid layout?

This is my layout xml to create the cards rows:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/card" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_b"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/card" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_c"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/card" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_d"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/card" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GridView for this situation. I put my very simplified codes here, so you can use them and change them as you need. This GridView has just 12 ImageViews.

1. Create an Adapter class for GridView:

MyGridViewAdapter.java

```
public class MyGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<Integer> drawables;


    MyGridViewAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    void setDrawables(List<Integer> drawables)
    {
        this.drawables = drawables;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return drawables.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create new ImageViews for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // main layout of each item of gridView:
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout=new RelativeLayout(context);
        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams((int)dpToPx(context, 100),
                (int)dpToPx(context, 100)));

        // images:
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        relativeLayout.addView(imageView);

        return relativeLayout;
    }

    private float dpToPx(Context context, float dp) {
        return dp * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    }
}
```

2. Add GridView to your activity layout:

activity_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TestActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

3. Use these codes in your activity:

TestActivity.java

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        // list of 12 images:
        List<Integer> drawables=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
        {
            drawables.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
        }

        // gridView adapter:
        MyGridViewAdapter adapter = new MyGridViewAdapter(this);
        adapter.setDrawables(drawables);

        // gridView:
        GridView gridView = findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                // what happen when you click on each item
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and the result:

[image: the result image]

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:rowCount="3" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/card" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_b"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/card" />

    .
    .
    .

</ GridLayout>
```

Read: https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/android-grid-layout-1faf0df8d6f2